# How filter list inside another list using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

How to get the comma separated URLs for `images:` having the `type:` **jpg** using java streams?
One product contains multiple images with different types.

```
 product A :{
    name: a
    images: [
      {
           img1: 1
           url: url1
           type: [
             {
               format: jpg
             }
             {
               format: png
             }

          ]
      },
        {
           img2: 1
           url: url2
           type: [
             {
               format: mp4
             }
             {
               format: png
             }

          ]
      },
      {
       img3: 3
       url: url3
       type: [
         {
           format: jpg
         }
         {
           format: mp4
         }

      ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Start by parsing the JSON

Comment: first, please fix your question first, that's not a valid JSON, string or key should be enclosed with double quotes (")

Comment: Please share your **attempt** and describe the problem you've encountered. You've specified the language and the preferred way of addressing the problem, but the question contains no code at all, only JSON-like sample data. The Questions on  StackOverflow are supposed to **provide value to future readers** (not only to the post author), therefore every question is expected to demonstrate an effort.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the model in Java (Collection of Image describing URL and Type), the usual approach is:

1. filter by type
2. map to URL, String
3. reduce using BinaryOperator

```
    static final BinaryOperator<String> reducer = (a, b) -> a + "," + b;
    static final Predicate<Image> isJpg = (i) -> i.types()
                       .anyMatch(t -> t.format == Image.Type.JPG);
    
    public static String getUrls(final Collection<Image> images) {

        return images.stream()
                .filter(isJpg) // filter type
                .map(Image::getUrl).map(URL::toString) // map to URL
                .reduce(reducer) // reduce to a separated string
                .orElse("No Match!");
    }
```

Comment: Image type is again a list, so we have to loop it again right to get the filtered one?

Comment: updated: `.filter(i -> i.getTypes().contains(Image.Type.JPG))`

Comment: again the types is an object not a list of strings

Comment: This is how you *could* model it in Java, but that's optional. You can have complexity wherever wanted instead. So far the object only consists of the single format-string. To have an enum in Java is quite usual.

Comment: the type is not a enum, it is an Object class contains multiple fields. one of the field is type.

Comment: @Jijo Sure, please take it in account when parsing the model and adapt accordingly. To get help on that, try to ask the specific question. Thanks